# Fit titles in sliding tabs

Tags: android, tabs, indicator

I'm developing android application using Sliding Tabs. I distributed tabs evenly but now when title of tab is longer tab indicator hides. I was wondering if there is way to fit titles in tabs but they stay distributed evenly?

Comment: Try `mSlidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);`

Comment: Actually google already mentioned in their documentation that try to use the smaller words instead of using long detail words...